# Adjust label fontsize

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I would like to adjust a label content dynamically; when the text is bigger adjust the label fontsize to fit in the label space.

```
<Label Name="lblResult" Content="0" Margin="0,-1,-222,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
       HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
       FontFamily="Helvetica Neue" Foreground="White" Background="Black"
       Height="87" FontSize="63" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Padding="9"
       ContentStringFormat="{}{0:#,0}" FontWeight="Light" ClipToBounds="True" />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The WPF Viewbox control will grow / shrink its contents to the available space:

http://www.wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html

Just place your Label within a ViewBox:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Label Name="lblResult" Content="Moez Rebai" VerticalAlignment="Top"
   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
   FontFamily="Helvetica Neue" Foreground="White" Background="Black"
   Height="87" FontSize="63" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Padding="9"
   ContentStringFormat="{}{0:#,0}" FontWeight="Light" ClipToBounds="True" />
</Viewbox>
```

Of course, your Viewbox is typically scaled by its container, but hopefully you get the idea!

Comment: When i put the label code in the Viewbox the label disappears, even when i run the code there's not any label

Comment: hi i edited the previous code, i tried with it and it works good. Could you please try it and tell me what you got.

Comment: did you get it or not